# "lassen" in meaning "sich fassen"

Tags: phrase

On [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lassen) it is said that one of the meanings of *lassen* is *sich fassen*.

So, can you help me, what does the following sentence, put as en example on wiktionary, mean:

> Und wenn dann rings umher sich Niemand vor Lachen zu lassen wußte, so saß er selbst, mit seiner großen, gebogenen Nase, […] (Thomas Mann, *Buddenbrooks*)

and what is *vor Lachen zu lassen* and what the verb *wissen* and preposition *vor* has to do with this?

Answer (score 6):

It is mind-boggling that Wiktionary pretends *die Beherrschung behalten* is a meaning of *lassen*. Quite obviously, *sich nicht zu lassen wissen* is an idiom, i.e. the meaning of the whole cannot be derived from the meaning of its parts: it does not mean *nicht wissen, wie man sich läßt*. A dictionary written by professionals of course acknowledges this fact.

> https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/lassen
>
> 7. sich nicht zu l. wissen sich nicht fassen, beruhigen können: Resi … hat sich vor Wiedersehensfreude gar nicht zu lassen gewußt KÄSTNER *Lottchen* 57; wenn dann ringsumher sich niemand vor Lachen zu lassen wußte TH. MANN 1,278 *(Buddenbr.)*

The preposition *vor* is not part of the idiom. It is used to introduce a causal adjunct, just as in *vor Wut rot anlaufen, vor Kraft kaum laufen können*.

Comment: Maybe they are referring to [Grimm > lassen 13 & 13b](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL01735#XGL01735) but omitting the "mit reflexivem acc:"

Comment: I love DWB. But if all the examples of *lassen* allegedly meaning *sich beherrschen* contain a negation, a reflexive pronoun and a verb with the meaning *be able to*, then we are dealing with an idiom and not a meaning of the word *lassen*.

Comment: Does it sound more like *sich beruhigen*, viz *lässig* - "Sie wussten sich gar nicht mehr zu beruhigen*? Grimm notes on *lassen* a variant "part. gelân" ... know *gellen*, PGem \*gellana "to shout", with pretty solid PIE roots. Perhaps this is a mix up? Cp. "Sie konnten nicht mehr vor Lachen". "3) *lassen verbindet sich mit einem objecte, etwas oder einen weichen machen, von sich lassen, entlassen, fortlassen, fahren lassen; in mehrfachen fügungen.*
a) *einen schrei, einen seufzer, thränen u. ähnl. lassen:* alsdann lest die fraw ein langen seufzer." see also 5) and compare "an sich halten".